# Compare historical data

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following function that is supposed to compare current and historical transactions for each id. The logic seems to work ok, but the performance is extremely low for the amount of data I'm processing (about 20 million records); more than 10 hours to run.  What can I do to improve the performance?

## Functions

```
def compare_historical(data):
    month_start = datetime.now().replace(day=1).isoformat()
    data_1 = data[data['trxn_datetime'] >= month_start ]
    data_1 = data_1[['id', 'amount']].groupby('id').agg(
            {'amount': 'sum'}).reset_index()
    data_n = data[data['trxn_datetime'] < month_start]
    data_n = data_n[data_n['id'].isin(data_1['id'])
    data_n = data_n.set_index('trxn_datetime')
    data_n = data_n.groupby('id').apply(
           lambda g: _compare_trend(g)).reset_index()

    data_1 = data_1.merge(data_n, on='id', how='right')
    data_1 = data_1[data_1['amount'] >= data_1[0]]
    data = data[data['id'].isin(data_1['id'])]

    return data

def _compare_trend(group):
    group = group['amount'].resample('1M').apply('sum')
    group = group[group != 0]
    mean = group.mean()
    std = group.std()

    return mean + 2 * std
```

## Testing

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests
from datetime import datetime

url="https://api.mockaroo.com/api/49d8d220?count=1000&key=1d2c2410"
s=requests.get(url).content
c=pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s.decode('utf-8')))
c['trxn_datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(c['trxn_datetime'])
compare_historical(c)
```

## cProfile-ing

Here is some profiling I did using the mock data (with 40 million records and 3135 ids). The only difference is that this data has a limited number of id's compared to actual data.

[image]

Comment: "*performance is extremely low*" - in what aspects? RAM, execution time? What are your current performance metrics?

Comment: I'm mainly talking about time, it takes about 10+ hours currently.

Comment: Have you tried using a profiler to figure out what part is running so slowly?  You need to figure out what the problem is before you can fix it; it might be that the slow part isn't even in your own code. 
https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

Comment: Thanks @SamStafford I added the cprofile.

Comment: The image is of limited usefulness, but seems to suggest that your Python code is fine actually. If you don't have enough memory to keep all the data in core, that's probably the root cause for the slowness (the OS ends up swapping memory regions out to disk and back in repeatedly, i.e. [thrashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thrashing_%28computer_science%29)).

Comment: It should be `data_n = data_n[data_n['id'].isin(data_1['id'])]`, you are missing the closing `]`. In addition, I get a `KeyError: 0` in the line `data_1 = data_1[data_1['amount'] >= data_1[0]]` when trying to run your code.